# cordova-plugin-contacts-Not get all event dates

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I have used following code to fetch the Contacts and the Contact details using contact plugin, "*cordova-plugin-contacts*"

```
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "";
options.multiple = true;
var fields = ["*"];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessContact, onErrorContact, options);
```

But I was not able to fetch the event dates like

1. Anniversary
2. Custom
3. Others

How to get these fields?

Comment: ...and I suppose the question is, how to get these? If so, please [edit] that into the question. Also please show us what you've tried so far. Good luck!

Comment: @Tojo This seems to be a plugin enhancement. Did you tried the same in Android device to cross check once?

Comment: Its the Plugin to fetch contacts . How you are excepting events data (anniversary ..etc) from it .

Answer (score 3):

Contacts plugin will return only few fields, refer https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#properties

And some properties supported in android, are not supported in ios device. refer device specific quirks https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#android-2x-quirks

You can get fields like birthday, displayname, id, phoneNumbers. But 
there is no support for fields of type anniversary,custom etc. 
You can get user-defined categories associated with the contact using categories field.

```
// find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter = "Bob";
options.multiple = true;
// Contact fields to be returned back.
options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id, navigator.contacts.fieldType.birthday];
options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
```